# Suitable method for user verification

Tags: php, macos

I am being asked to limit access to my member's section of a website.

I have integreated the email and password login system.

it gives access to the users with correct email and password from any computer.

Now i am being asked to limit per email, per computer...

I am wondering how? planning for mac address or user computer. So how can we get the user computer's mac address? or is there any better idea?

I am writing my app in php

I have been reading how to do it from c#: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/2b125a0e-f67d-476f-b8a0-a21c99279d5b/

Comment: What does it mean "limit per email"?

Comment: specific email address can access system from specific computer only

Comment: Setting a cookie one be one way to identify a machine that a user registered from, but Cookies can be cleared, so it's not fool proof. MAC address is no good especially if the user is behind a proxy. Since you can only work within the constraints of a browser, you have very limited options.

Comment: is your server being regular internet-wide web-site or some sort of local intranet site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is simple: **No. Way.**

No way to get MAC address nor "user computer" whatever it means

(with only one exception: it is possible if your server is sort of local intranet site)

Comment: Yes, the only identifying pieces of information are IP address which can change and user agent string, which can be forged.

Comment: Probably checking IP will be enough for this guys employer, the request itself is pretty stupid

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, turn on output buffering and execute external program to display output.  Capture the output into a variable and clean the output buffer.

```
<?php
ob_start(); // Turn on output buffering
system('ipconfig /all'); //Execute external program to display output
$mycom=ob_get_contents(); // Capture the output into a variable
ob_clean(); // Clean (erase) the output buffer
$findme = "Physical Address";
$pmac = strpos($mycom, $findme); // Find the position of Physical text
$mac=substr($mycom,($pmac+36),17); // Get Physical Address
echo $mac;
?>
```

Comment: don't know the reliability of ipconfig /all command in linux but liked the way you used the system command for collecting information

Answer (score 0):

Well

> MAC Address is limited in Local Area
>   network,you can't get the details for
>   anyone's MAC Address from Internet.

The Other things you can track

1. Using Computer IP address
2. Using HTTP user header

You can allow the list of known ip address to have access to your website using [.htaccess file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

If they are logging in from a Windows network then you can make use of a project like http://phpad.sunyday.net/ This would work for an intranet site only though.

There are few alternatives, but as others have mentioned they can be spoofed.

If it can just be by IP then you can set this in your .htaccess file. For example:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from 192.168 # for a subnet
Allow from 192.168.0.23 # for a particular IPV4 address
```